# Like likes like

Tags: proverbs, sayings

The popular English saying:

> **Birds of a feather flock together.**

Which means: people of the same sort or with the same tastes and interests will be found together.

I also heard the similar saying:

> **Like likes like.**

My questions:

- Does it exist in English or it a translation from another language?
- If it exist, then, does it mean the same as: "birds of a feather..."?

Comment: "Like likes like" isn't a common, everyday expression. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: ***Like likes like*** is just a wordplay/pun. I'm sure it won't be a translation from another language, because it's highly unlikely any other language has a single word with those two completely distinct senses - noun ***like = ilk, type, kind*** and verb ***like = prefer, choose, rather have***. So the "pun" wouldn't work in any other language.

Answer (score 1):

**Like likes like** is a phrase in English, and it is used in English. It has the same meaning as "birds of a feather flock together," that is, *people who are similar enjoy each other's company*. However "birds of a feather" is used far more often, [according to Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+likes+like%2Cbirds+of+a+feather+flock&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and has become much more common since the mid-1990s.

I will point out that "like likes like" is something of a [tongue twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue_twister) which may account for its relative rarity.

Comment: My father used to say 'Like cleaves unto like', which I suspect, may be Biblical.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Google didn't find much as a true quote. It had some mumblings on Quora [yeah, quora] mentioning it in relation to slavery, abolitionists & what they 'really thought'. The only publication I could find with it as quoted was a Latter Day Saints book from 1865… but they had it in quotes, so presumably it was already known. My trail went cold there…

Comment: "Like Likes Like" was a children's book, pub 1999.

Comment: There is another saying "[judge someone by the company they keep](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+man+is+judged+by+the+company+he+keeps)".